# wcf - choosing what services to load from config file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have multiple *WCF services* pretty much independent one of the other which form together a nice core system. Third parties integrate to our system very easy, everyone is happy... BUT

The problem appears when we would like to restrict the usage of certain WCF service(s) for certain customers, based on certain licenses. Because we don't want to allow this opportunity for third parties to edit the config file and get full access to all our wcf services.

So, how could I restrict the usage of certain service(s)? I was thinking maybe there is an option to select which service to load from config file (based on the license). Is that possible? What other options would I have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a managed app (e.g. console app or Windows NT Service), you're basically in control of creating and managing the `ServiceHost` instance(s) that will "serve up" the WCF services.

Extending that service host, you could implement any kind of flexibility in loading the appropriate WCF services you need.

Read more:

- [MSDN: Custom Service Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx)
- [Composing WCF services with MEF](http://www.timjroberts.com/2011/08/wcf-services-with-mef/) (based on a custom `ComposableServiceHost` class)

Comment: Hi Marc. Actually the app is hosted in IIS... will go through your links... Thanks

Comment: @Cristi: well, in that case - you might need to create a custom `ServiceHostFactory`, too, that will instantiate your custom service host, and then you can basically do the same things.

Comment: Is my first time I hear about MEF, so probably I need to search a bit more about it :)... Any good links to get me started?